# $O \setminus X$ is open, and $O$ is open $\implies X$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $O,X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, with $O$ open and $O \setminus X$ open.

> Prove $X$ is closed.

My try: I want to prove that for every $p$ in $X^c$ I can find an open ball about $p$ that is entirely in $X^c$.

Let $p \in X^c$. If $p \in (O \setminus X) \cap X^c=O \setminus X$ then I can find an open ball about $p$ entirely contained in $p \in O \setminus X \subseteq X^c$. If otherwise $p \in O^c \cap X^c$ then I can find an open ball about $p$ entirely contained in $O^c$ because $O$ is open, but here I get stuck, since this ball don't need to lie entirely in $X^c$.

In my application I also have $X \subseteq O$ which ensures I can conclude, but I was wondering if in general the property could be proved true.

Comment: It’s not true ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: in your statement, take n = 1, O = {x : 1 < x < 3} and X = {x : 2 is less than or equal to x and x is less than 4}

Comment: Consider open interval $O=(0,2)$ and $X=[1,2)$ in $\mathbb R$

Comment: It's not true even if you assume $X \subseteq O$: in $\Bbb{R}^2$, take $O = \{ (x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2< 1\}$ (the interior of the unit disc) and $X = \{(x, 0) \mid -1 < x < 1\}$ (the intersection of $O$ with the $x$-axis). (Or you could even just take $X = O$.)

Comment: I guess you want to prove that $X$ is closed in $O$, which is true by definition. In topology, the reference is important because of the definition of subspace topology. In the above counterexamples, $X$ is not closed in $R$ but closed in $O$.